# Проверить первый символ слова-строки на регистр

Tags: php

Есть ли функция, которая позволяет узнать, является ли первый [0] символ строки - прописная или строчная буква?
Если нет, то какие есть способы написания такой функции?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$str = 'the text to test';
if($str{0} === strtoupper($str{0})) {
   echo 'yepp, its uppercase';
}
else{
   echo 'nope, its not upper case';
}
```

[первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2814891/5398808)

Comment: хотя ссылка и ведь на so, лучше опубликовать код ответа здесь, а ссылку привести как первоисточник.

Comment: @DavidKern, сделайте чтобы работало http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdc738979b7aa3aa79bcb98355942d060f3ef6af

Comment: Это если у вас строка не в многобайтовой кодировке, ага.

Answer (score 3):

Проверка для UTF-8 на прописную букву с помощью регулярного выражения и [свойств](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.unicode.php) Unicode-символов:

```
preg_match('%^\p{Lu}%u', $str)
```

Пример http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad7171cbca77386187f4cf4f38a1f484a27ac506

```
<?php

function first($str) {
    if(preg_match('%^\p{Lu}%u', $str)) {
        var_dump($str . ' - прописная');
    } else {
        var_dump($str . ' - строчная');
    }
}

first('Привет мир!');
first('привет мир!');
first('the text to test');
first('The text to test');
first('123');
first('');
```

Результат

```
string(41) "Привет мир! - прописная"
string(39) "привет мир! - строчная"
string(35) "the text to test - строчная"
string(37) "The text to test - прописная"
string(22) "123 - строчная"
string(19) " - строчная"
```

Comment: поправьте пожалуйста ссылку, по ссылке код с предыдущего ответа